# facebook messenger send message api without the user initiating the chat

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-send-api

I have a facebook page, and a website too. I need to add a button to my website, like "SEND THIS ARTICLE ON MESSENGER". When the user clicks on it, I need to send the article data to the user on messenger.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: "without the user initiating the chat" - not possible.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve your goal, You must have to use **SEND TO MESSENGER** Button.

Ref.: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin/

Full process to implement:
 1. Need to integrate Facebook Div in your site
 2. Add Facebook script 
 3. Once Any User press the button than You got the webhook event from the facebook which contatin the **PSID**.
 4. Through this PSID You can sent the messege to that id.

If you are sending message using curl than following is the code

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{  
  "recipient": {
    "id": "<PSID>"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<FB_PAGE_TOKEN>";
```